# FragmentFirstBinding Error with First Fragment XML Changes

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm in Bumblebee v.2021.1.1. I don't have any database elements in my project. I do have defaults in the first fragment:

```
import com.my.app.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding
```

in:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

    _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
...
return binding.root
}
```

When I make changes to fragment_first.xml the FirstFragment.kt file blows up: In Android Studio the problems tab reads Unresolved reference: FragmentFirstBinding and Variable expected, each several times for each occurrence. I don't understand the Logcat much at all. The only way I've found to correct it is to remove the null safety (?) from:

```
    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
```

and then to just add it (the question mark) back in.

Also, I've seen about making databinding true in the build.gradle file, but it was not the default when I chose the Basic Activity template when starting the project. Is it stable to add databinding = true to the build.gradle file?

Comment: put your output error too

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I should have been specific about the error. I've adjusted my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank goodness! I believe the IDE and Kotlin code both work beautifully and I'm right. I have found the error is generated only if a fragment file and a related XML file are running at the same time.

For example: if I open FirstFragment.kt and leave it open and then open and edit fragment_first.xml then the .kt (Kotlin) file gets the error.

But I don't get the error if I don't have the fragment file open, and then change the XML and then open the fragment file for editing.

In other words, when I make changes to a related XML file and then open the related Kotlin file, it can analyze and adjust to the changes made to the XML file that it has to bind to.

In addition, in an attempt to be clear, it looks like having only one tab (one file) open in Android Studio may prevent this from happening.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).